# Using ASP.Net MVC, Ajax, and Partial Views, how can I update my url?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Ok, so I am trying to have a static menu on the left side of the page so that it doesn't change when click on a link.

How I am doing this is I call a little javascript on my A tag that calls some ajax. My controller returns a Partial View which then is loaded into my content div.

This all works fine. What I am having trouble with is that my URL isn't changing and I would like to be able to use the back button to go back to a previous page.

I have tried to use location.hash but that doesn't seem to work in the way that I hoped. Thoughts?

Below is my code.

HTML

```
<li class="item3"><a href="#">Admin</a>
<ul>
    <li class="subitem1"><a onclick="ChangePage('/Admin/PageName', 'Hash')">Page Name</a></li>
```

Javascript

```
function ChangePage(path, hash) {
        $.post(path, function (data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
            window.location.hash = '#' + hash;
        });
    }
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult PageName()
    {
        return PartialView("MyPage");
    }
```

Thanks!
David

Comment: Another way of asking this question is how do I get a side menu  that functions like gmail...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider checking out [pjax](http://pjax.heroku.com/). It's very easy to implement w/ MVC, and will do exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

[This article](http://kazimanzurrashid.com/posts/asp-dot-net-mvc-with-pajax-or-pushstate-slash-replacestate-and-ajax) talks about another option, PAjax.

Both leverage `pushState`, which as you stated in the comments, is still not fully supported by all browers. But pjax does gracefully degrade by doing a full page update when pushstate is not supported.

Comment: I have thought about using pushstate, but it seems as though the browser support on that is really weak still.

Comment: As far as I can see, pushstate is the only way to accomplish updating the URL w/ Ajax. But you're right, some older browsers (and maybe IE) don't fully support this. Fortunately, pjax gracefully degrades, but only if that's acceptable for you.

Comment: Taking a look at pjax as we speak :)

Comment: The second link about PAjax did the trick. Awesome. Thanks so much!

Comment: FYI...another helpful link: http://biasecurities.com/2011/04/using-pjax-with-asp-net-mvc3/